# Get timestamp with milliseconds in Javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime, formatting, timestamp

I want to get the current date including the milliseconds. I know that `Date.now()` is returning the Unix epoch time in milliseconds, but the object `Date` contains only the Date and timestamp with second precision.

```
console.log("Time: " + new Date);

Time: Tue Apr 14 2020 12:21:26 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)
```

But I want it to look like this:

```
Time: Tue Apr 14 2020 12:21:26.500 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)
```

Is there a way to change the format in order to display the milliseconds as well or do I need to concatenate the `Date` string with `new Date().getMilliseconds();`?

Comment: as far as I can see this is parsing a time format including milliseconds into JS timestamp, what I want is the other way around, to get the current timestamp and visualize it with millisecond precision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `moment.js` to achieve the format you need, and the other option is to concatenate manually

```js
console.log(moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SSS'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.16.0/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: If you are just formatting dates, there are very much smaller libraries than moment.js, e.g. [fecah.js](https://github.com/taylorhakes/fecha) (not a recommendation, just an example).